# How to SetDefaultCertificate from the client to invoke Server web method in WCF

Tags: wcf

Below are the configuration setting i have in Server web.config file which is WCF application. Here i used makecert.exe for creating X509 certificate.

`<serviceCredentials>
<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType= "WcfService1.CCustomValidatorClass,WcfService1"/>
            <serviceCertificate
       findValue="CN=SignedByCA1"
       x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"
       storeLocation="CurrentUser"
       storeName="My" />
          </serviceCredentials>`

"CN=SignedByCA1" is the Private Key and now , I want to invoke Web Method on WCF service from the Client.
But i need to set SetDefaultCertificate from the Client, could you please help how can I get key for accessing Private key X509 Certificate.

`ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();`

```
        obj.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Sukesh";
        obj.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Sukesh";

        obj.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser, 
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
             System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
             "XYZ");

    string str = obj.GetData(1); // web method
```

Please help me here...

ERROR: {"The X.509 certificate CN=SignedByCA1 chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode. The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.\r\n"}

Thanks,
Sukesh.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error due to a self signed certificate.

You can either ignore the error using, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.100).aspx

or you could install the client certificate into the server's trusted root authority (assuming this is just for development).

Or, of course, you could get the certificate signed.

Comment: I can provide some more detail if you can update your post with more information.  The error occurs on the server?  Can you post the system.servicemodel section of your web config?

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply, could you please tell me how to create client certificate based on the Server private key certificate.

Comment: I am able to paste server web.config file, but unable to submit with Add Comment button.

Comment: It's too big to add as a comment, edit your opening question and add it there.